# Leading zero using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to add leading zero in my records, but it doesn't work then I have no idea to solve this. the data as follow

| textmess | convert |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | 08 |
| 8 | 008 |
| 14 | 014 |

this is the query i have run

```
Select right('000' + rtrim(ltrim(cast(TEXTMESS as varchar(3)))), 3) convert, TEXTMESS from mytable
```

I thought it would work but it didn't work for first row, it should be 008 right? why the result is different with second row? . please help to solve this query

Comment: You might have unprintable character after `8` for first row. The data type for `textmess` is string type ?

Comment: What is the datatype of your `textmess` column? Is there a reason you included `rtrim` and `ltrim`?

Comment: the data type for textmess is varchar. I thought it because there are space or something, that's why i am using rtrim dan ltrim

Comment: To debug, you can check how long the original text is. Select textmess, len (textmess ) from mytable

Comment: It should work with your current attempt. Check for invisible special characters by retriving the hex values of that particular row with `CONVERT(VARBINARY, TEXTMESS)`. Ignore the initial 0x and check the last 2 characters of the result on a ascii, unicode or the proper table for the data stored in that column. Then use `REPLACE`  to remove it.

Comment: @EzLo I already run as your advice, and I found the difference. for "08" is using "0x381C"
and for "008" is using "0x38". how to replace or remove  "0x381C" to become "0x38"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a special non-visible character in that row. First check that varchar value in hex to check which character code is it:

```
Select 
    right('000' + rtrim(ltrim(cast(TEXTMESS as varchar(3)))), 3) AS Converted,
    TEXTMESS,
    CONVERT(VARBINARY, TEXTMESS) AS HexValues
from 
    mytable
```

Seems that for a row you have `0x38` and for the other `0x381C`. Assuming that the values are in ASCII, `38` is the 8 and `1C` is the hex for symbol FS (file separator).

If you check any ASCII table online, you can see that the code for FS is `28`, so just use `REPLACE` with `CHAR(28)`. Check the result first:

```
Select 
    right('000' + rtrim(ltrim(cast(TEXTMESS as varchar(3)))), 3) AS Converted,
    TEXTMESS,
    REPLACE(TEXTMESS, CHAR(28), '') AS Replaced,
    right('000' + rtrim(ltrim(cast(REPLACE(TEXTMESS, CHAR(28), '') as varchar(3)))), 3) AS ReplacedConverted
from 
    mytable
```

Then remove the character with `UPDATE` for all rows that have any FS:

```
UPDATE T SET
    TEXTMESS = REPLACE(TEXTMESS, CHAR(28), '')
FROM
    mytable AS T
WHERE
    CHARINDEX(CHAR(28), TEXTMESS) > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can go for FORMAT and apply preceding 0.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(textmess int)

insert into @table 
values (8),(8),(14)

SELECT textmess, FORMAT(textmess,'000') as convertedTExt from @table
```

| textmess | convertedTExt |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | 008 |
| 8 | 008 |
| 14 | 014 |

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT RIGHT('000'+CAST(textmess AS VARCHAR(3)),3)convertedText, textmess from mytable
```

Comment: I already try this one but it does not work.

Comment: which version of sql server are you using ?

Comment: Please stop saying "does not work". Please explain or post an error message